# Cortex m3 svc with gcc inline assembly

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly, cortex-m, thumb

I hope to make a svc # into c code. Now I can use assembly to take up the value of svc.

```
SVC_Handler:
   tst  lr, #0x4
   ite  eq
   mrseq    r0, msp
   mrsne    r0, psp
   b    SVC_Handler_C

   void SVC_Handler_C(unsigned int *svc_args)
   {
       unsigned int svc_number;
       svc_number=((char *)svc_args[6])[-2];
```

But I hope translate it to inline assembly in c code. But I found the sp will be modify by function entry by local variable or something. Is any possible to solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you just want inline assembly code. If this is the case then try the following:

```
__attribute__((naked)) void SVC_Handler(void) {
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "   tst     lr, #0x4            \n\t"
    "   ite     eq                  \n\t"
    "   mrseq   r0, msp             \n\t"
    "   mrsne   r0, psp             \n\t"
    "   b   SVC_Handler_C           \n\t");
}
```

Then write your `SVC_Handler_C` as a normal C function.

Comment: If you write it like that, also make it `__attribute__((noreturn))` ;-)

Comment: Can you elaborate why is attribute `noreturn` needed as well? Thanks.

Comment: Not _needed_ but a good idea because it stops the compiler from creating the "normal" return at the end of the function (`b lr`). Just check the disassembly differences when you compile the above with / without it.

Comment: I think that `naked` attribute implies the the generated assembly will not contain `bx lr` or `pop {pc}` instructions at the exit point of the function. At least, I have never seen GCC generate entry/exit code when `naked` attribute is specified. Btw, I compiled above code with `naked` and `noreturn` and got a: `warning: 'noreturn' function does return`, but the generated assembly is same in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

Slight change over BlueSky's version:

```
__attribute__((naked)) void SVC_Handler(void) {
    register unsigned int *svc_args __asm__("r0");

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "tst     lr, #0x4
         ite     eq
         mrseq   %0, msp
         mrsne   %0, psp" : "=r"(svc_args));

    return SVC_Handler_C(svc_args);
}
```

I'm surprised though that you're not considering simply making the C function the handler directly, and retrieving the argument via the above little inline assembly block.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly, as the end of the function handler has no return, due to naked.  As a result, the code falls out into the next adjacent code, and in my case gets stuck in an infinite loop calling SVC_Handler_C which as adjacent.

Comment: @WieserSoftwareLtd there might be a compiler dependency there. In cases where I tried, the compiler did _not_ do a `bx` for the `return SVC_Handler()` (but tail-recursed, via direct `b ...` and therefore _cannot fall through_) . What's your generated assembly ? See also BlueSky's last comment above - that's _very_ relevant.